# Fail opening file from server php openlayers

Tags: php, linux, permissions

I am trying to use my webpage in linux. I created it on windows and I am getting an strange error. I guess it is related to permissions.

I don't know what is the problem now, in windows it works fine but when I try the same in linux, I get this error:

`Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permiso denegado in Unknown on line 0`

`Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/open/listaZonas.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0`

Permiso denegado means something like Permissions not allowed

I have a server with xampp (lampp) and there, my webpage is hosted. After, I have an eclipse tomcat server which serves a REST service.

In my webpage I call this rest service to give me a file but I read it through a php file which is in my xampp server:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']); 
?>
```

I pass in url, the url of my rest service.
It works fine on windows and I can read the desired file without problems but now I don't know what is happening.

do I have to configure something in xampp server? php or something to read this file...
I placed all files where they have to be.

Comment: Use `chmod` to set the file access permissions on /opt/lampp/htdocs/open

Comment: re: Moving code from win to linux - watch out for case sensitivity in file names too.

Answer (score 0):

turn on the terminal and run in the parentfolder of htdocs/ as root

```
chmod -R 777 htdocs/
```

with that you make the whole htdocs folder readable, writable and executable. I dont recommend it for a server accesible from the internet due to security reasons but for local usage its just fine.

Also set the folderowner to the user of the webserver if there is one with `chown`.